# Exporting Feature Class to Shapefile in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, convert, arcgis-10.4

ArcGis 10.4

I have to create buffers in the ModelBuilder.
At one point I have a feature class from which I have to spatially select some items (via tool "select by location"). But this tool does not allow a feature class as an input parameter.

The only thing that works is to seperate the work flow. If I run the model until this point and then manually take the produced output, the select by location tool accepts this as an input. But of course that destroys the workflow and will not let me do any iterations for example.

Unfortunately I cant find an option to export this featureclass (to a shapefile?) and google is not helping me either. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Select Layer By Location or Attribute works with Feature Layers only. Use the GP tool before passing it further http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your model builder (at least with the output before select by location)